# Remove part of column name

Tags: regex, r

I have a `df` with column names of `a.b.c.v1, d.e.f.v1, h.j.k.v1`, and would like to remove `v1` from all the column names of `df`.

I suppose I should use `gsub` but my trials with that were not successful.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also, add your code even if it didn't work, it might help to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the `.v1` from the end of the string.  (If we only need to remove 'v1', just remove the `\\.` from the pattern to match, but I think a `.` at the end of column name may not look that good).  Here, we match the dot (`\\.`) followed by one of more characters that are not a dot (`[^.]+`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with `""`.

```
colnames(df) <- sub('\\.[^.]+$', '', colnames(df))
colnames(df)
#[1] "a.b.c" "d.e.f" "h.j.k"
```

Comment: yes, it works but it returns only list of of column names with removed v1. but i would like to preserve df structure.

Comment: @Olga Sorry, I am not sure I understand your comment.  This remove the end of the string with `.v1`.  How is this changing the structure of 'df' as we are only dealing with column name?

Comment: yes, but it returns character vector containing column names with removed v1

Comment: check out your data.frame. The names should have changed

Comment: @Olga As I understand the question, you want to remove the substring .v1 from the column names.  This does what you mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Olga, check head(df), this code definitely removes the '.v1' from the names of the data frame columns